# Query Django JSONFields that are a list of dictionaries

Tags: django, django-jsonfield

Given a Django JSONField that is structured as a list of dictionaries:

```
# JSONField "materials" on MyModel:
[
    {"some_id": 123, "someprop": "foo"},
    {"some_id": 456, "someprop": "bar"},
    {"some_id": 789, "someprop": "baz"},
]
```

and given a list of values to look for:

`myids = [123, 789]`

I want to query for all MyModel instances that have a matching some_id anywhere in those lists of dictionaries. I can do this to search in dictionaries one at a time:

```
# Search inside the third dictionary in each list:
MyModel.objects.filter(materials__2__some_id__in=myids)
```

But I can't seem to construct a query to search in all dictionaries at once. Is this possible?

Comment: Where is the "2" coming from?

Comment: 2 means "search in the third dictionary in the JSONField list on each MyModel instance. The question is how to eliminate the 2 and search in all dictionaries of each list.

Answer (score 2):

[contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std:fieldlookup-hstorefield.contains) might help you. Should be something like this:

```
q_keys = Q()

for _id in myids:
    q_keys |= Q(materials__contains={'some_id': _id})

MyModel.objects.filter(q_keys)
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm very familiar with using `contains` expressions in JSONField queries, but that's actually not the interesting bit here. The interesting bit is that you are building up a Q query incrementally by iterating through the target matches. Not sure how that will scale if comparing to thousand of possible matches in a single query, but I will do some experiments and report back.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've posted another answer containing a custom function I wrote to accomplish this, using this "incremental Q building" technique.

Answer (score 2):

Given the clue here from Davit Tovmasyan to do this by incrementing through the match_targets and building up a set of `Q` queries, I wrote this function that takes a field name to search, a property name to search against, and a list of target matches. It returns a new list containing the matching dictionaries and the source objects they come from.

```
from iris.apps.claims.models import Claim
from django.db.models import Q


def json_list_search(
    json_field_name: str,
    property_name: str, 
    match_targets: list
    ) -> list:
    """

    Args:
        json_field_name: Name of the JSONField to search in
        property_name: Name of the dictionary key to search against
        match_targets: List of possible values that should constitute a match

    Returns:
        List of dictionaries: [
            {"claim_id": 123, "json_obj": {"foo": "y"},
            {"claim_id": 456, "json_obj": {"foo": "z"}
        ]

    Example:
        results = json_list_search(
            json_field_name="materials_data", 
            property_name="material_id", 
            match_targets=[1, 22]
        )

        # (results truncated):
        [
            {
                "claim_id": 1,
                "json_obj": {
                    "category": "category_kmimsg",
                    "material_id": 1,
                },
            },
            {
                "claim_id": 2,
                "json_obj": {
                    "category": "category_kmimsg",
                    "material_id": 23,
                }
            },
        ]
    """

    q_keys = Q()
    for match_target in match_targets:
        kwargs = {
            f"{json_field_name}__contains": [{property_name: match_target}]
        }
        q_keys |= Q(**kwargs)

    claims = Claim.objects.filter(q_keys)

    # Now we know which ORM objects contain references to any of the match_targets 
    # in any of their dictionaries. Extract *relevant* objects and return them
    # with references to the source claim.
    results = []
    for claim in claims:
        data = getattr(claim, json_field_name)
        for datum in data:
            if datum.get(property_name) and datum.get(property_name) in match_targets:
                results.append({"claim_id": claim.id, "json_obj": datum})

    return results
```

Comment: looks great, will save it for future use

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(materials__contains=[{"some_id":myids}])
```

Be careful when using `[{ and }]`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise *not* to use a [**`JSONField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField). In relational databases, `JSONField`s nearly always break [*first normal form* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and the case that you want to search over all records actually proves that it breaks first normal form: all columns should be treated as *atomic* values in the sense that you don't want to look at substructures. But here you clearly do that.

Especially since the data is structured, there is no reason to use a `JSONField`, use an extra model with a [**`ForeignKey`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass


class Meterial(models.Model):
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(
        MyModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='materials'
    )
    some_id = models.IntegerField()
    some_prop = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

and then query with:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(materials__some_id__in=[123, 789])
```

Comment: Despite breaking first normal form, JSONFields are *incredibly* powerful and useful. All tech choices are compromises of one sort or another, and millions of use accept the compromises of JSONField because it unlocks so much potential. Our app has tons of standard FKs and dozens of JSONFields. When you need 'em, you need 'em.

Comment: @shacker: a JSON field itself does not per se compromises first normal form. As long as you see the blob as something "atomic", as in you don't need to filter, aggregate and update *parts* of the blob. Furthermore it breaks *relational* databases, and to be honest, I never really understood why everyone went for that model in the first place :).

Comment: @shacker: the problem is also not that much with writing a query, or retrieving data. The problem starts to occur when *filtering* data efficiently for example, since now we have to look in all JSON blobs, whereas relational databases keep indexes, which guarantee referential integrity and speed up filtering, where often one does not have to go through the json blobs. You can make GIN indexes, but that only partly solves the problem: https://www.metisdata.io/blog/how-to-avoid-performance-bottlenecks-when-using-jsonb-in-postgresql

Comment: @shacker: but as a rule of thumb: if the data has a fixed structure, like it does here, a JSON field is not a good idea. JSON is a recursive (context-free) language. It is normally used if the structure is not fixed, or hierarchical with arbitrary depth. Like you say: when you need'em, you need'em. But here clearly you don't need'em. Your question funny enough proves that :).